# Xpath to find inner text

Tags: java, selenium

How do I write xpath for the text "sku0111" in the below picture given in the click[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZoVm.jpg)

Have tried this

```
driver.findElementByXPath("(//span[@class='a-list-item']/b/following-sibling::text())[2]");
```

But it throws invalid selector exception though the xpath shows 1 of 1 element in DOM when inspected.

Comment: It belongs `span` tag, not in `<b>` tag

Comment: First, please avoid link to pictures for code samples. Second, the "sku" is not a sibling as it is not in an XML tag. I think you have an issue here with mixing text content with your `<b>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findElements` instead :

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElementsByXPath("//span[@class='a-list-item']/b/following-sibling::text()");
System.out.println(elems.get(1).getText());
```

or

```
 String org = driver.findElementByXPath("//span[@class='a-list-item']").getText();
 String[] arr = org.split(" ");
 System.out.println(arr[1])
```